# How can I count the same characters can I find in a .mat file (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, character, matlab-figure

So I got a .mat file of characters that shows me the places people have been to. Some of those places repeated and I want to know how to count them in .mat file.
Let's say, 'NewYork' 'NewYork' 'Florida' 'California' 'Florida' 'Nevada'

'NewYork' appeared twice, as well as 'Florida', 'California' and 'Florida' only appeared once.

I want to show: NewYork = 2 Florida = 2 California = 1 Nevada = 1

I have no idea how to start my code.

Comment: Any chance you could post the script that generates the `.mat` file or the `.mat` file itself. Depending on how the strings are configured/saved the implementation may vary.

Answer (score 0):

### Test `.mat` File Creation

All the workspace variables will be saved using the `save()` function.

```
Cities = ['NewYork' 'NewYork' 'Florida' 'California' 'Florida' 'Nevada'];

%Saving the workspace variables into 'Cities.mat' file%
save('Cities.mat')
```

### Loading `.mat` File and Counting the Cities

To load a `.mat` file simply use the `load()` function with the filename as input. To count substrings of the char/character array use the `count()` function. The `count()` function will take two input the first is the character array/string to be checked and the second is the substring to check for. The `count()` function will return the number of times the substring appears in the larger character array/string.

To get the statements/results to print the command window the command `fprintf()` is used. Everything within the `""` quotation mark will be printed and the `%d` placeholder will be replaced by the value as an `int` of the corresponding second input argument in `fprintf()`. Along with this you can save all the counts as variables by calling the `save()` function once again. These variables can be loaded in for viewing at anytime by clicking the `.mat` file in the current folder side panel or by using the `load()` function once more.

[image: Image Displaying Results]

```
clc;
clear;
load('Cities.mat');

NewYork_Count = count(Cities,"NewYork");
Florida_Count = count(Cities,"Florida");
California_Count = count(Cities,"California");
Nevada_Count = count(Cities,"Nevada");

fprintf("NewYork = %d\n",NewYork_Count);
fprintf("Florida = %d\n",Florida_Count);
fprintf("California = %d\n",California_Count);
fprintf("Nevada = %d\n",Nevada_Count);

save('Cities.mat')

%Additional message box output%
msgbox(sprintf(' NewYork = %d\n Florida = %d\n California = %d\n Nevada = %d',NewYork_Count,Florida_Count,California_Count,Nevada_Count));
```

### Alternative Output Modal/Message Box:

[image: Ouput Message Box Image]

```
%Additional message box output%
msgbox(sprintf(' NewYork = %d\n Florida = %d\n California = %d\n Nevada = %d',NewYork_Count,Florida_Count,California_Count,Nevada_Count));
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**